# What's up with umlauts in English?

Tags: orthography, german

I've been seeing words with umlauts in prominent publications - for example The New Yorker [spells](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2017/01/30/doomsday-prep-for-the-super-rich) re-election like this:

> reëlection

What's going on?

Comment: As used in English words, the punctuation mark is called a [dieresis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dieresis).

Comment: That's so you will know you're reading *The New Yorker*.

Comment: [Another *New Yorker* article](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2023/07/24/how-gretchen-whitmer-made-michigan-a-democratic-stronghold) spelling reelection as reëlection.